# Need to force http to https and then only force user to login using htaccess and apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite, https

I know how to force http to https, and I know how to use htpasswd to force someone to login to the site. But I need a combination of this. Basically the site needs to be forced to https, and then the authentication needs to happen. Therefore there will be no http access to the site whatsoever.

Can anyone supply me with working htaccess code to do this please? I've seen [this thread](http://forum.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=61566) a couple of times, but it is not what I want.

Comment: Do you have access to the main Apache configuration file?

Comment: The site is hosted on a VPS running WHM and cpanel, so I guess so, but I'd rather not mess around in cpanel's apache config file. There might be a custom config file per site, so please let me know what you had in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess directives are processed sequentially, so you should be able to have the SSL redirect at the top and  then later followed by your authentication requirements. So, the code might look something like this at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note the [L] will prevent it from going further in case the access was non-HTTPS. Then later on in the file you can have some variant of this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/.htpasswd
```